# Use R to check the language for non-Unicode programs

Tags: r, unicode

In R, function `Sys.getlocale()` can show current locale in R. But if language for non-Unicode programs is incompatible with the language used, e.g., in the data, encoding related problems arise. I need to check if is both language for non-Unicode programs (e.g., on Windows in Fig. 1) and R locale are set correctly.

**How to check the language for non-Unicode programs programmatically in R?**
Maybe the function `system()` would be handy here.

I'm user of Windows but I'm also interested if a similar setting (language for non-Unicode programs / system locale) is present on Mac and on Linux.

[image: Fig. 1]
**Fig. 1** Setting system locale on Windows.